# RESTKit communication error

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, restkit

I am trying to consume an XML web service through RESTKit.

I am able to connect to the service but I am receiving an error back as follows:

```
error=Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type (null), got application/xml"
```

I have tried setting the content type header as follows but still not getting any change:

```
AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:RKMIMETypeXML];
```

Hopefully somebody can help.

I have included the code I am using to  make the request below:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someaddress/"];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeXML];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeXML];

RKObjectMapping *recipeMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Recipe class]];
[recipeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"articleid" : @"ArticleId",
 @"title" : @"Title",
 @"url" : @"URL"
 }];


// Register our mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:recipeMapping
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:@"Recipes"
                                                                                   statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"some/path/"
                     parameters:nil
                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                            NSArray *recipes = [mappingResult array];
                            NSLog(@"Loaded statuses: %@", recipes);
                        }
                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }];
```

The problem is that I am still getting the Expected content type (null), got application/xml error message.

Furthermore, I have made a call to the service URL with via a very quick and easy sample ASIHTTP app and this is successful. I must be missing something fundamental.

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing RestKit and AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Martin mentioned you don't need to talk to the AFHTTPClient directly as this point.

```
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
[manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have amended my code accordingly but this is not making a difference i.e. I am still getting     Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type (null), got application/xml". I am going to update the above with more code sample